# how to send nested array to server with Retrofit 2

Tags: android

I'm trying to send a request to server with Retrofit 2, one of my parameters should be like this:

> [["Ingredient","amountInt","unit"]]

That the inner list is dynamic,and it can be many of these! like below

> [["Ingredient1","1","kilo"],["Ingredient2","2","kilo"]]

I've tried to make this arrays with `List<String[]>`  and `JSONArray` and `List<List<String>>` 
But none of them works and I get time-out from server
I get my request with insomnia and postman , and I get success response

This is my Retrofit Interface

```
@POST("my server link")
Call<MyResponse> addFood(
        @Header("token") String token,
        @Part("name") RequestBody getName,
        @Part("time") RequestBody getTime,
        @Part("description") RequestBody getDescription,
        @Part("hardness") RequestBody getHardness,
        @Part("group") RequestBody getGroup,
        @Part("numberOfPeople") RequestBody getNumberOfPeople,
        @Part("tags") RequestBody getTags,
        @Part("source") RequestBody getSource,
        @Part("ings")List<String[]> ings);
```

And this is how I creat my ings:

```
String[] getIngs=new String[3];
ArrayList<String[]> ingsFinal= new ArrayList<>();
getIngs[0] = getIngredient;
getIngs[1] = getAmount;
getIngs[2] = getUnit;
ingsFinal.add(getIngs);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: for timeout issue, use OkHttpClient and set connectTimeout and readTimeout. because retrofit default timeout is 10s

Comment: @DivyeshPatel the problem is my parameters that I send and I think it's not the exact format that my server wants, becouse in Insomnia, it's all working!

Comment: I used Json string as BODY parameter to pass to server  and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> I get time-out from server

When server received wrong params it should create respons with some error.
Time-out depends on internet connection or incorrect url.

You should check `Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl()` and `@Post()` urls.
`baseUrl = "http://url.url/"` `postUrl="path/path"`

Comment: my urls are okay, I've test what you said, and removed one parameter from what I send to server in Insomnia, and I've got time-out error too!!

Comment: @AzinNilchi What value of `ings` key in request logs?

Comment: I've tested to send ings with List<List<String>> and server gets :
['["ings","number","unit"],'["ings2","number2","unit"]']
ther is an extra cotation around the iner brockets!
same thing happened with List<String[]>